# Compile Bootstrap with Grunt from my own project's Gruntfile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

I'm building a project which is going to use a customized version of Bootstrap. I forked the `twbs/bootstrap` repo and my project uses Bower to check out a specific branch of my forked repo to my project's `/bower_components` directory. That all works fine.

My own project has a Gruntfile. My goal is that when you clone my repository and run the command `grunt dev` it runs the `grunt dist` command of the checked out Bootstrap bower component. I tried using the `grunt-bower-concat` plugin but that only handles JS, and doesn't compile the Bootstrap LESS files. In addition my task needs to run some other tasks such as bower_concat (which grabs only the JS of Bower-included files).

Basically I want to do something like this:

`grunt.registerTask('dev', ['Bootstrap:dist', 'bower_concat', ...]);`

where `Bootstrap:dist` points to that registered task of the Bootstrap Gruntfile. Is there a (maintained) plugin that will auto-compile Bootstrap assets and spit them out (or move them) to a specified directory?

My goal is to not have to re-create the LESS compilation tasks myself since it's possible that Bootstrap will change them in the future.

Comment: Should note that I want it to be a fresh build where I can copy everything from /dist to wherever I need it.

Comment: The LESS compilation task shouldn't change anymore for v3. For v4, things are likely to change drastically enough to break your build system anyway. The LESS compilation task isn't very complicated anyway; might as well copy-paste it in and tweak it a bit, IMO.

Comment: Also, Bower sucks. I know of no good reason to choose it over the other available frontend package managers, which all seem more featureful.

Comment: What other package managers would you recommend?